# GTK quit dialog box by using gtk_widget_destroy?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk2

I write an simple application to show a yes/no dialog box. Here is my program:

```
static gint confirmation_dialog()
{
GtkWidget *label;
GtkWidget *box;
GtkWidget *dialog;
gint response;
gtk_init(NULL,NULL);
/* If we use convenience API function gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons,
    * last six function calls can be written as: */
dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons( "Confirmation",
                                        NULL,
                                        GTK_DIALOG_MODAL,
                                        GTK_STOCK_YES, GTK_RESPONSE_YES,
                                        GTK_STOCK_NO,  GTK_RESPONSE_NO,
                                        NULL );

/* Create label */
label = gtk_label_new( "There is new update, do you want to proceed?" );

/* Pack label, taking API change in account. */
 #if GTK_MINOR_VERSION < 14
box = GTK_DIALOG(dialog)->vbox;
#else
box = gtk_dialog_get_content_area( GTK_DIALOG( dialog ) );
#endif
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), label, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

/* Show dialog */
gtk_widget_show_all( dialog );
/* Run dialog */
response = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
//gtk_widget_hide( dialog );
gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
return response;
}
```

When I click to yes or no button, the response value is returned. But the program can not quit the dialog box. Can everybody help me find out the problem?
Many thanks.

Comment: Show some [MCVE] - without it, your question is unclear. So **edit your question** to improve it. BTW, update to GTK3. Compile with all warnings and debug info `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`.  Improve your code to get no warnings, then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand what goes wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].